# How to draw google.visualization.datatable after click event?

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

How to draw datatable after click event?
I have next js code:

```
function drawDataTable() {

var options = {'showRowNumber': true};
var query = new google.visualization.Query($('#connection_spreadsheet_url').val());


function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    var data = response.getDataTable();
    (new google.visualization.Table($('#table')[0])).draw(data, options);
}

function sendAndDraw() {
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(sendAndDraw);
```

}

It's work fine, but I want drawing datatable only after clicking button (for example **$('#button')**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(sendAndDraw);
```

with something like this:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
    $('#button').click(sendAndDraw);
});
```

This ensures that the API is loaded before you can try to use any components.  You might want to disable the button initially and enable it when the callback runs, so the user doesn't have an "I clicked this and nothing happened" issue (in the event that the API loads slow).

Comment: Thank you very much!
Nice and simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/9Rawe/ I know it's not a datatable but it should work pretty much the same way all the google visualizations

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load('visualization', '1', {
                'packages': ['corechart'],
                "callback": drawChart
            });
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
                    ['2004', 1000, 400],
                    ['2005', 1170, 460],
                    ['2006', 660, 1120],
                    ['2007', 1030, 540]
                ]);

                var options = {
                    title: 'Company Performance'
                };

                $("#button").click(function() {
                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="submit" value="Display Chart" id="button" />
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```